# How Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...) updates the UI controls in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, dispatcher

I read that Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() will run in a separate thread from ThreadPool.

Is it correct?

If it is correct then my question is: If it running is separate thread which is not UI thread, how it will update the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` schedules an action to be called *on* the UI thread and is called from a *background thread* to update UI elements.

Comment: Yes, background thread means any thread but the UI thread. The UI thread in WPF has a [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) registered against it, which schedules in work around the rendering.

Comment: Thanks, but little clarification on "any thread but the UI thread". There will be only one UI thread, then how secondary thread will update UI thread?

Comment: @Syed - Dispatchers work like a worker queue on a loop. The background thread adds a callback into the queue and the UI thread runs it when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks, I marked as correct answer. Example or video link which explanins these concepts will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In ordinary WPF application all UI objects are associated with a single dispatcher and the dispatcher is associated with a single thread. BeginInvoke asynchronously runs a specified delegate on the thread associated with the dispatcher (in the case of a UI dispatcher it will be the UI thread). You only need to call BeginInvoke (or the Invoke which is same as BeginInvoke but blocking) from a thread other than the UI thread.

If you want to update UI from a code running in a ThreadPool's thread, get the reference to the UI dispatcher and call BeginInvoke or Invoke and it will transfer the call to the UI thread.